# Windows info char, similar to "®"

Tags: windows, winforms

I don't find a windows char for info.

I need something like ® char just to have i inside circle. I need it on windows form app.

Comment: Use `"\u00ae"` in code.  Or type Alt+0174 on the keyboard.  Or copy/paste from the Windows charmap.exe utility.  Do experiment with charmap.exe, it will answer your next question about unusual glyphs.

Comment: @xDan can't you use an icon/image? At least it won't be dependant on the font in use in the system. If that's not a problem then just pick the relevant Unicode character (check the font...):  ⓘ (U+24D8 CIRCLED LATIN SMALL LETTER I). There is also the equivalent upper case character, both as outline and reversed with solid background)

Comment: Yes i am doing it now by picture, i thought there is allready some integrated font that has the char. It seems it does not. Thanks for comment, put it as answer I will set it as answer.

Comment: @xDan there is (see second part of the comment) and _please_ no need to do anything _weird_ with the string (in C# you can also escape unicode chars in the string with `\u`) but not every unicode char is supported by ms sans serif then you should check for each case (and it may vary across OS versions).

Comment: If you want to actual real "pretty" Windows `i` icon, you can get it from the [Visual Studio Image Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/the-visual-studio-image-library), which is freely available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#9432;")`

Or alternatively there is `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#128712;")` Which is a little bolder and clearer.

Example:

`Dim myString As String = "This string contains the information symbol: " & System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#128712;")`

You can find codes for these symbols and more here : https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm

***Edit***

Adding comment from @Adriano Repetti as a possible solution too.

@xDan can't you use an icon/image? At least it won't be dependant on the font in use in the system. If that's not a problem then just pick the relevant Unicode character (check the font...): ⓘ (U+24D8 CIRCLED LATIN SMALL LETTER I). There is also the equivalent upper case character, both as outline and reversed with solid background)

Comment: _"...I need something like ® char just to have i inside circle..."_. He does not need ® (which, anyway, can be typed/inserted directly inside a string).

Comment: Bugger! my bad i thought it said " i need 'it' inside the circle"

Comment: Have edited to print the 'i' inside a circle symbol instead

Comment: `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`?! What for? You can paste printable character inside the string literal. That said: `Convert.ToChar()` is usually easier (and faster) to use; it is worth to be mentioned that default UI font (ms sans serif) does not support most unicode _special_ characters then OP should check case by case (this one is supported, anyway).